# Contar colores en google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un script que me crea una formula para google sheet, la cual cuenta un color determinado en un rango determinado de celdas, el problema que estoy teniendo es que cuando modifico el color de una de las celdas de dicho rango el valor no se actualiza.

Este es el script que tengo:

```
function contarcolor (color, inputRange) {

  var inputRangeCells = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(inputRange);
  var rowColors = inputRangeCells.getBackgrounds();
  var count = 0;

  for(var r = 0; r < rowColors.length; r++) {

   var cellColors = rowColors[r];

    for(var c = 0; c < cellColors.length; c++) {

      if(cellColors[c] == color) {

         count++;

       }

     }

   SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  }
  return count;

}
```

Imagino que pare que el resultado se me actualice debería de utilizar la función OnEdit, pero no consigo ver como utilizarla en este caso.

Comment: no veo que estés usando el `.setBackground('color');` osea en que momento en tu código "editas el valor" , lee esta documentación https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list

Comment: @DiegoMesa no utilizo el `.setBackground('color');` puesto que es una función personalizada, y el color, si te fijas lo adquiere del rango de celdas que le indicas.

Comment: @DiegoMesa Si te fijas, ademas, al ser una función personalizada también le estoy pasando el color que estoy buscando mediante un parámetro,

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que por "crea una formula" quieres decir que el script es una función personalizada la cual la pones en una celda de la hoja de cálculo como fórmula `=contarcolor ("#FF0000", "A1:B5")`, esta no se actualiza cuando realizas cambios en la hoja de cálculo porque las funciones personalizadas sólo se actualizan al abrir la hoja de cálculo y cuando se modifica uno de los argumentos de la función personalizada. Si te decides agregar un tercer argumento ten en cuenta que las funciones personalizadas no pude tener como argumento funciones volátiles como `AHORA()`, `ALEATORIO()`, etc.

Para usar tu función con `onEdit` en lugar de hacerlo en una formula, deberás indicar la celda en la que quieres que se escriba el valor, por ejemplo:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var color = '#FF0000';
  var inputRange = 'A1:B5';
  e // Objeto evento
  .range // Intervalo editado
  .getParent() // Hoja editada
  .getRange('A1') // Intervalo de destino
  .setValue(contarcolor (color, inputRange)) // Agregar resultado de la funcion contar color al intervalo de destino
}
```

Comment: El unico problema que veo aqui, es que voy a tener que agregar varios rangos distintios a distinguir y cada uno de estos rangos tendra su propia celda para escribir el resultado, lo que me generaria una cadena de `if` bastante importante.

Comment: @IvánMontero En lugar de `if` usa `switch`